# Laravel DI issue

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have made a `UserRepository` and implemented interface with methods it should hold. After that I have registered it within my service provider which is also registered in `app.php`.

```
class UserRepository extends AbstractUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->model = $user ?: $this->getAuthenticatedUser();
    }
    ...
}
```

`UserRepository` extends `AbstractUserRepository` which extends `EloquentRepository` which is supposed to abstract some generic eloquent actions.

`EloquentRepository` has a protected member `model` and its getter `getModel()`.

Now the issue I have is that the initialization doesn't seem to work as it should. After I log in and dump this from the test route:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    $repo = new \Account\Repository\UserRepository();
    return $repo->getModel();
});
```

I am getting back the authenticated user.

However if I use DI to do the same thing, I am getting an error:

```
use Account\Contracts\UserRepositoryInterface as UserRepository;

private $userRepository;

public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}
```

And then do a dump in the controller method

```
return $this->userRepository->getModel();
```

I am getting an error.

Specifically, it seems as if it is trying to initialize `User` model, but fails because user isn't actually forwarded

**EDIT all bindings:**

```
    $this->app->bind('User', User::class);

    $this->app->bind('UserRepository', UserRepository::class);
    $this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, UserRepository::class);

    $this->app->bind('AbstractUserRepository', AbstractUserRepository::class);
    $this->app->bind(AbstractUserRepositoryInterface::class, AbstractUserRepository::class);


public function provides()
{
    return [
        'User',
        'UserRepository',
        UserRepositoryInterface::class,
        AbstractUserRepositoryInterface::class,
        'AbstractUserRepository',
```

Comment: This is not the best idea. Just use `Auth::user()` . You probably don't want to bind the `User` class to the DI container just to inject the current user since that will tie your hands if you need to use model binding.

Comment: Use it where? Completely instead of repository?

Comment: Basically don't pass a user to the repository and have it use the authenticated user in all cases.

Comment: Well yeah, that would all be well if the project isn't made with repository pattern, and there are a ton of methods which are to be used with it, and I can't just switch it out. So I need to fix this and figure out why doesn't it work

Comment: Have you bound the `User` class to the container?

Comment: Yeah, everything is bound

Comment: Can you share your user binding code?

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: The user binding doesn't return an existing user but rather an empty user. Not sure if that's your intention here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163006/discussion-between-norgul-and-apokryfos).

Comment: What's the error you get ?